# Running .sh every 5 minutes

Tags: bash, scripts, desktop-background, schedule

I have a .sh script that downloads a photo from Japanese satellite's server and sets it as a background picture. I've put it into startup list, but how do I run it every, like, 5 minutes, automatically?

Comment: Try out cronmaker.com , there you can make cron-expressions and put it with crontab -e

Comment: Does the picture even change every 5 minutes? Try using an interval that creates less unnecessary load on the target server. Or make sure you only download if the file is really changed.

Comment: By the way, what's the url for the space backgrounds?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### The lazy option

*If* you want the easy way, and avoid having to find out which environment variable to set:

- Make sure your script includes the shebang
- Make it executable
- Add the following to Startup Applications:

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && while true; do <path_to_your_script.sh> ; sleep 300; done"
  ```

  Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && while true; do <path_to_your_script.sh> ; sleep 300; done"
  ```

#### Explanation

If you run the script from your own environment (e.g. from a terminal window or from Startup Applications), a number of environment variables will be set. `cron` however runs your script with a limited set of environment variables. 
Since your script no doubt uses the `gsettings` command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri <wallpaper>
```

to set the wallpaper, almost certainly the command will break when run from `cron`.

The downside of "the lazy solution" is purely theoretical. A command that sleeps practically continuously means *nothing* to your system.

#### Additional info; alternatively

Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666729/1391444), and from experiences in the past, I am pretty sure the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable needs to be set.

To do so, add the following section at the beginning of your script (below the shebang):

```
PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)
```

Then you should be able to successfully run it from `cron`.

You could however very well save the hustle, and choose the lazy option.

Comment: @AleksanderMahnyov You' re welcome. Glad it works :)

Comment: Ah, fun, a downvote. Care to share *why*?

Comment: It's so much better to use a cron job.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili Thanks for the comment. However: a. And why is that? a sleeping command means *nothing* to your system. b. I even included the option.

Comment: I didn't see the mention of cron. As your answer is the accepted one, it would be better to add instructions for cron. There are multiple reasons why you'd prefer using cron; I can give you a few - that's the standard way for scheduled tasks; if the system restarts, it will still continue to run; crashing once won't affect subsequent runs (you won't have to check if it's still running); it already has features you may otherwise end up re-implementing, e.g. running on the same time every day, running as a different user, etc.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili a. deliberately including (parts of) answers of others is a bad thing, the fact that this is the accepted answer does not change that. b. The option runs the command only for this user (startup applications is local) , no multiple runs of the command (other users even wont't want it) . c. If the system restarts it will run.

Comment: @JacobVlijm a. you can post an update with attribution and link to the other answer, pretty standard b. every user has her own cron, and I didn't mention any other users c. I don't see 'no multiple runs' as a benefit, both ways impose minimal tax on the system.

Comment: Otherwise, nice research about the gnome session variables, it would help the OP a lot, since that would be required either way.

Comment: I Just looked: `cpu 0.0%` What tax are we talking about?

Answer (score 29):

Put it in your `crontab`.

Open your `cron` table by:

```
crontab -e
```

Now add:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Don't forget to make the script executable beforehand.

---

As your script depends on X, probably will be a good idea to add the `DISPLAY` to the script's environment:

```
*/5 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /path/to/script.sh
```

Replace `:0` with your actual `DISPLAY` (can be found by `echo $DISPLAY` from interactive session).

If needed, you can add the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable too:

```
*/5 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY="~/.Xauthority" /path/to/script.sh
```

Again you can find the value by `echo $XAUTHORITY`.

Comment: Not sure if it works with limited environment variables of cron, but let' s see if OP mentions it works :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm If any additional variable is needed, OP can define those in the script, no neeed for `cron`..

Comment: Absolutely, but it can be tricky, and not so straightforward to set up (find out) sometimes.

Comment: Hm, it does not seem to work, while the script itself works, if I try to run it manually.

Comment: @AleksanderMahnyov Please [edit] your question to add the script, hard to say without seeing the contents..possibly a `DISPLAY` (and/or `XAUTHORITY`) issue..

Comment: @AleksanderMahnyov For starter, do one thing: make the `cron` entry as `*/5 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /path/to/script.sh`  Replace `:0` with your actual display found from `echo $DISPLAY`

Comment: @heemayl That won't do, I am pretty sure the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS environment variable` needs to be set when editing `gsettings`.

Comment: @JacobVlijm hmmm..hard to get to a conclusion without seeing the contents..

Comment: @heemayl That is for 5 seconds, not 5 minutes. Try `* /*5 * * * /path/to/script.sh` for 5 minutes.

Comment: @Kartagis Cron can not handle seconds, also you are trying to do for hours which is still syntactically wrong..

Comment: Oops, you are right, sorry

Comment: I love this method rather than the "lazy method", because I knew about cron, but needed a bit of a refresher course. This is exactly what I did, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Better approach than the accepted answer. :)