# Background not changing using gsettings from cron

Tags: gnome, cron, environment-variables, gsettings

I'm trying to change my wallpaper to a random image using Indrajith Indraprastham's suggested script here:
[How to change desktop background from command line in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity/510135#510135)

When I run the script from a terminal window, the bg changes just fine, but when it's run from cron, I'm mailed this error:

> (process:21901): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=00216c114dcf433c9bb9009985d607d6 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: @Merri apart from the fact that the *answers* there do not solve the problem of OP (which wouldn't make it a dupe by the way), How would this be a dupe????  Same error does not mean it is the same question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Editing gsettings from cron; missing environment variable

If you run the script from your own environment (e.g. from a terminal window or from Startup Applications), a number of environment variables will be set. `cron` however runs your script with a limited set of environment variables.

To edit `gsettings` successfully from `cron`, you need to set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable. You can do that by adding two lines to your script, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666729/1391444) (and below).

#### Your script, including setting the needed variable

The script [from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/510135/72216), edited to include the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable, then becomes:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)

DIR="/home/indra/Pictures/wallpapers"
PIC=$(ls $DIR/* | shuf -n1)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$PIC"
```

---

Related: [Running .sh every 5 minutes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738180/running-sh-every-5-minutes/738195?noredirect=1#comment1097406_738195)

Comment: @Shaun You' re welcome! Glad it works :)

Comment: I am trying this with Cinnamon on Mint.
When I run this from the cli directly, I get "dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The given address is empty". It used to work before (from cli), without the PID and DBUS_SESSION_*. (But not from cron)

Comment: @donquixote Try `PID=$(pgrep -f 'gnome-session' | head -n1)`!

Comment: You can replace `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)` with `$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ)` Since grep gets the variable name too. [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/979326/301745)

Comment: Not working on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: `pgrep gnome-session` may return more than one pid if multiple users are logged into the system (each running gnome-session). Perhaps `EUID=$(id --real --user)` and `PID=$(pgrep --euid $EUID gnome-session)` would be a way to get only the PID associated with the current user's gnome session.

Comment: Or perhaps $(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [@jacob-vlijm](https://askubuntu.com/a/743024/123916) didn't work for me because of a few shell script issues (the `$(id --real --user)` command was returning more than one line, and the `grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-` command had a null byte error).

Here's one that works without issues (at least for me):

```
#!/bin/bash

REAL_UID=$(id --real --user)
PID=$(pgrep --euid $REAL_UID gnome-session | head -n 1)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2- | sed -e "s/\x0//g")

DIR="/home/indra/Pictures/wallpapers"
PIC=$(ls $DIR/* | shuf -n1)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$PIC"
```

Comment: This solution as of today is more reliable then the original answer.