# Unable to run .sh script for cron task. Changing background image

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, cron, gsettings

I have tried several approaches to fixing this issue, but all I want to do is change the desktop wallpaper when this script is run in cron. Below is what I have so far.

```
PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/mark/Pictures/Background_Pictures/CAP.jpg
```

I get the following error when I run this in cron.

```
(process:17154): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

I know that part of the problem is that I need to set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable, but I have and it seems to have a valid value.

I'm at a loss as how to accomplish this. Does anyone have a valid solution for this?

Comment: Are you trying to use `cron` to set your desktop wallpaper?

Comment: Yes. I can't get cron to successfully run the command I specified above without errors.

Comment: Within `System Settings` -> `Appearance` it can cycle through wallpaper I believe.

Comment: I'm trying to set specific times on a particular day when I want the wallpaper to change. Not just like a slideshow.

Comment: a) do you need `sudo`? and b) you might need `dbus-launch`

Comment: I've attempted without sudo and also with dbus-launch. Neither have worked.

Comment: Is this a user crontab or a root crontab? Have you tried `DISPLAY=:0 gsettings` in place of `sudo gsettings` ? (adjust `:0` if that's not the target display)

Comment: There are three answers to your question here, one of them using cron script: http://askubuntu.com/questions/835853/how-can-i-get-one-wallpaper-for-each-day-of-the-week

Comment: I just used DISPLAY=:0 instead of sudo and I got this message instead.
"(process:24089): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I used the following script.

```
PID=$(pgrep gnome-session) 
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-) 
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/mark/Pictures/Wallpapers/CAP.jpg"
```

However, the issue was in my cron file. I was using the line

```
***** root sh /home/mark/scripts/desktop.sh
```

when it should have been

```
***** mark sh /home/mark/scripts/desktop.sh
```

When I ran the script in cron with my own privileges, then I was able to run the script in cron successfully.