# How to use 'set | grep' in script correctly in order to obtain a value of DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

I need to obtain a value of DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and save it to a file.

If I run `set | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > /home/user/.DBUS_temp` in Bash I have something similar to `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-N1wmwpEVBj` in the `.DBUS_temp` file which **is OK**.

But when I try to run the command in script the following happens:

1. An empty file is created if `set | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > /home/user/.DBUS_temp` is used.
2. `BASH_EXECUTION_STRING='set | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > /home/user/.DBUS_temp'` is in the file if `su -c 'set | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > /home/user/.DBUS_temp' user` is used.

What is wrong in my code/implementation?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There's no reason to `set | grep`. Just `echo "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" > file` would work better in most case. Here, are you running the script in cron?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/742870/background-not-changing-using-gsettings-from-cron

Comment: @muru Thanks for your reply. I put the line into /etc/rc.local for it is run every time I switch on my PC.

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` is waay too early for that. This variable is set when you login from the GUI.

Comment: @muru Thanks again for your kind comment and the link. I'll dive into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this answer to my own question to close it.

Thanks to help of [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/) and [the answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742870/background-not-changing-using-gsettings-from-cron) I figured out how to obtain the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable in the form of `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-N1wmwpEVBj` which is suitable for my purpose (using this I don't even need to save the variable to the file):

```
PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)
export $(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ)
```

Using code from the mentioned answer ends up in obtaining just `unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-N1wmwpEVBj` part of the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable. It does not work for me.

Comment: "Using code from the mentioned answer ends up in obtaining just "... That's why it does `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=...`.

Comment: @muru Thanks again for your clarification. I'm not skilled Bash user and your suggestions were to the point.