# Automatic Light / Dark Mode?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

Has anyone found a way to automatically switch between "light" and "dark" modes yet, with regards to the "Window Theme" in Ubuntu's settings (Settings → *Appearance* → *Window Theme* → *Light / Standard / Dark*)?

Digging into the settings *every* morning or evening is a real pain. It'd be great to be able to *automatically* switch to "dark" mode at sunset, and *automatically* switch to "light" mode at sunrise.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For GNOME, this shell extension exists: [Night Theme Switcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2236/night-theme-switcher/)

It has quite a lot of options and already works out of the box, without having to configure anything, but the configuration is straight forward as well!

[image: Screenshot of the Schedule tab]

[image: Screenshot of the GTK theme tab]

Comment: This is a great extension, thanks for it.

Comment: I installed it but don't understand how to open it.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian that's a thing with gnome extensions - it's really not clear how to open the settings if you don't know. there's a few ways. if you installed the extension using the gnome extensions browser add-on, you can open the preferences from there. otherwise, you might want to use `gnome-tweaks` or using the command line: `gnome-extensions prefs nightthemeswitcher@romainvigier.fr`

Comment: does it work with 22.04? when I click _install_ on the linked page, it opens a dialog that tells me _no apps available_

Comment: Also the extension page says `Ubuntu is not supported due to their heavily patched GNOME components that conflict with the extension`

Answer (score 12):

The terminal command for changing theme is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru-dark
```

for the Yaru-dark theme, and

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru-light
```

for the Yaru-light theme.

Now, there's something called cron-job for scheduling jobs (basically executing something, repeatedly at specific time). So, you can write a cron-job to execute these commands at specified times (something like change to dark theme at 9 PM and light theme at 6 AM).

Add the following to a file named `script.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > lightscript.sh
echo export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > darkscript.sh
echo "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru-light" >> lightscript.sh
echo "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru-dark" >> darkscript.sh
chmod 755 lightscript.sh
chmod 755 darkscript.sh

currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
if [[ "$currenttime" > "21:00" ]] || [[ "$currenttime" < "06:00" ]]; then
  ./darkscript.sh
else
  ./lightscript.sh
fi
```

Make the file executable running:

```
chmod 755 /path/to/script.sh
```

or:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script.sh
```

Run `gnome-session-properties` in terminal. Add a new start up program by clicking add on right side and selecting the `script.sh` file by browsing and save it with some name and comment. This will tell GNOME to create `lightscript.sh` and `darkscript.sh` whenever you login through GUI.

Add your job (change theme) to `crontab` by using the command:

```
crontab -e
```

and choosing a suitable editor or you can go to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` and edit the file with your username. Accessing the file this way requires `sudo` privileges. Add the following two lines (with `/path/to/` replaced by actual path):

```
0 6 * * * /path/to/lightscript.sh
0 21 * * * /path/to/darkscript.sh
```

It will say:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
```

after exiting the command. You can also check with:

```
crontab -l
```

This should do it. The above two lines tell `cron` to execute `lightscript.sh` at 6:00 AM and `darkscript.sh` at 9:00 PM everyday.

We are taking this detour instead of just adding:

```
0 6 * * * gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru-light
```

to `crontab` because this requires the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable to be set correctly.

Comment: nice answer....

Comment: I followed the instructions... We'll see in about half an hour whether I have done it right and / or how well it works. But why do your instructions refer to two different scripts at the end (lightscript.sh and darkscript.sh), when you are indicate that I should create a single script at the start (called "script.sh")?

For the last section (with the reference to the two scripts), I changed the name to "script.sh" for both of them, because I only created a single script at the start... I also change the times (from "21" to "18", for 6PM).

Comment: It didn't work... :-(

Comment: So, the file "script.sh" is executed when you login (provided you added it in gnome-session-properties). Its work is to create lightscript.sh and darkscript.sh with proper value for DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS. Then the crontab executes these lightscript.sh and darkscript.sh. Just restart and login and see if lightscript.sh and darkscript.sh is created where script.sh is present. Also try `service cron status` to see if cron is running

Comment: This wouldn't work with changes you made to the script names @GregoryOpera

Comment: All right, I went through the process again - this time leaving the script names as "lightscript.sh" and "darkscript.sh"... We'll see if it works in the morning, when I wake up (the computer usually stays on).

Interestingly, I now have a "lightscript.sh" and "darkscript.sh" file in my "home" directory...

Comment: Edited the script

Comment: Went through the whole process again - after you edited the script above - exactly as stated (i.e. using lightscript.sh / darkscript.sh), then I restarted my computer... I appreciate your suggestion - but this solution simply does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107619/discussion-between-shubhzgang-and-gregory-opera).

Comment: Hi i tried it when I first commented above.. it worked.. working still.. I followed the instructions as it is..

Comment: As noted above, I went back and started the process again, following the instructions to the letter... Still doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, I found a command to remove ALL cron jobs, so I did that and went through the process again... The ONLY thing I changed is the "21:00" was changed to "18:00" in the script code above, and also when creating the cron job (i.e. "21" was changed to "18").

I'm gonna reboot now, and see if it works this time...

Comment: Still didn't work... Nothing.

I had a window Files / Nautilus window open at 1800 to see if the changes would be applied, with my desktop unlocked (i.e. not on the "lock" screen)... Nothing happened.

Comment: Downvoting! the answer has been made more complicated than it should be

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve this with the help of `crontab` and [@shubhzgang](https://askubuntu.com/users/586903/shubhzgang)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1234819/895417).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Script that auto switches Ubuntu themes to Dark or Light, 
# depending on the time of day

# Copy this script file to /usr/local/bin/my-auto-theme
# Add following lines to crontab -e
# 0 9 * * * bash /usr/bin/local/my-auto-theme light
# 0 17 * * * bash /usr/bin/local/my-auto-theme dark
# @reboot bash /usr/bin/local/my-auto-theme

set_theme() {
    if [[ "$1" == "dark" ]]; then
        new_gtk_theme="Yaru-dark"
    elif [[ "$1" == "light" ]]; then
        new_gtk_theme="Yaru-light"
    else
        echo "[!] Unsupported theme: $1"
        return
    fi
    
    # https://askubuntu.com/a/1234819/895417
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
    current_gtk_theme=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme)
    # echo "[.] Currently using ${current_gtk_theme}"
    if [[ "${current_gtk_theme}" == "'${new_gtk_theme}'" ]]; then
        echo "[i] Already using gtk '${new_gtk_theme}' theme"
    else
        echo "[-] Setting gtk theme to ${new_gtk_theme}"
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ${new_gtk_theme}
        echo "[✓] gtk theme changed to ${new_gtk_theme}"
    fi
}

# If script run without argument
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
    if [[ "$currenttime" > "17:00" || "$currenttime" < "09:00" ]]; then
        set_theme dark
    else
        set_theme light
    fi
else
    set_theme $1
fi
```

We added `@reboot` so that script runs even if PC was shut down at cron trigger time.

Answer (score 0):

I work on a script to do that, and I like the result, it works similar to gnome autodarkmode, with a sunshine and sunrise time, take a look at:

https://github.com/jackfido/nightMode

You need to have internet conection to get the sunrise and sunset data, this ocurrs here:

getSunRiseAndSet.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1.- Tihs files pretends to get the sunset and sunrise values from: https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/mexico/
# 2.- To save this values into a temporal file, called as the "yourlocation".out
# 3.- Then compares the dates; from the last modified file date to current date in format YYYYmmdd to determine if we have the today values
# 4.- If the file is for yersterday or older then we have to go for the values for today, else, do nothing 
# 
# Additional:
#       run THIS file in startup applications to run when your session start after a shotdown or reboot
#       run crontab -e to run nightMode.sh file, directly, every minute to set theme as soon as the sunset/sunrise occurss -> * * * * * ~/Public/nightMode/nightMode.sh
#       run THIS task each 3,4, 6 or 8 hours, it depends on how many times you want to check if you download the updated file, it allow us to have the values up-to-date in case of pc enters in hibernatin or freeze state during a day change

# file name and location
location="monterrey"
tmpfile=~/Public/nightMode/tmp/$location.out

# get dates from last file and current
lastUpdate=$(date -r $tmpfile +"%Y%m%d")
currentDate=$(date +%Y%m%d)

# if file doesnt exists
if [ ! -z "$lastUpdate" ]; then
    # compare file date with current date to determine if need download the values
    if [ "$lastUpdate" -lt "$currentDate" ]; then
        wget -q "https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/mexico/$location" -O "$tmpfile"

        echo "Monterrey time getted successfully"
        bash ~/Public/nightMode/nightMode.sh
    fi
else
    wget -q "https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/mexico/$location" -O "$tmpfile"

    echo "Monterrey time getted successfully"
    bash ~/Public/nightMode/nightMode.sh
fi
```

nightMode.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
location="monterrey"
tmpfile=~/Public/nightMode/tmp/$location.out

SUNR=$(grep "Sunrise Today" "$tmpfile" | grep -oE '((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))' | head -1)
SUNS=$(grep "Sunset Today" "$tmpfile" | grep -oE '((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))' | tail -1)

# Use $sunrise and $sunset variables to fit your needs. Example:
sunrise=$(date --date="$SUNR" +%Y%m%d%H%M)
sunset=$(date --date="$SUNS" +%Y%m%d%H%M)

hour=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)

if [  $hour -gt $sunrise ] && [ $hour -lt $sunset ];
then
    bash ~/Public/nightMode/day.sh
fi

if [ $hour -lt $sunrise ] || [ $hour -gt $sunset ];
then
    bash ~/Public/nightMode/night.sh
fi
```

day.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

PID=$(pgrep compiz)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)

# theme2Stablish='Materia-light-compact'
theme2Stablish='Yaru'
theme=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme)

if [ "$theme" != "$theme2Stablish" ];
then
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme $theme2Stablish
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-light'
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Papirus-Light'
#    notify-send "Day theme stablished"
fi
```

night.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

PID=$(pgrep compiz)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)

# theme2Stablish='Materia-dark-compact'
theme2Stablish='Yaru-unity-dark'
theme=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme)

if [ "$theme" != "$theme2Stablish" ];
then
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme $theme2Stablish
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-dark'
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Papirus-Dark'
#    notify-send "Night theme stablished"
fi
```

then add nightMode to crontab:

```
# Create with crontab -e command:

* * * * * ~/Public/nightMode/nightMode.sh
0 */6 * * * ~/Public/nightMode/getSunRiseAndSet.sh
```

I started working based in this page

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-obtain-sunrise-sunset-time-for-any-location-from-linux-command-line

And then, in your programs configure the automatic darkmode, like in github desktop, Android Studio, firefox, etc, etc

this was my result:

Light Mode:

[image: Light Mode]

Dark Mode:

[image: Dark Mode]

Regards

Comment: Hello. What about later when the link does not work? Maybe include the info in the body of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using Shubhzgang's answer and a couple of more answers from other sources. Then added my own modifications. Here's the script I use:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script that auto switches Ubuntu themes to Dark or Light, 
# depending on the time of day

# Copy this script file to /usr/local/bin/switch-theme.sh
# Add following lines to crontab -e
# 0 10 * * * bash /usr/bin/local/switch-theme.sh light
# 0 19 * * * bash /usr/bin/local/switch-theme.sh dark
# @reboot bash /usr/bin/local/switch-theme.sh

set_theme() {
    # https://askubuntu.com/a/743024/1193214
    # PID may return multiple ids here, so I converted to to array and got just the first id.
    # Otherwise, you may try another suggestion in the link https://askubuntu.com/a/1437023/1193214
    PID=($(pgrep gnome-session))
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)
    echo `date` Starting script execution - setting theme $1 >> ~/Scripts/switch-theme.log
    if [[ "$1" == "dark" ]]; then
        new_gtk_theme="Yaru-blue-dark"
        # Some apps also need color scheme
        new_color_scheme="prefer-dark"
        new_icon_theme="Yaru-blue-dark"
    elif [[ "$1" == "light" ]]; then
        new_gtk_theme="Yaru-blue"
        new_color_scheme="prefer-light"
        new_icon_theme="Yaru-blue"the
    else
        echo "[!] Unsupported theme: $1"
        return
    fi
           
    current_gtk_theme=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme)
    current_color_scheme=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme)
    if [[ "${current_gtk_theme}" == "'${new_gtk_theme}'" ]]; then
        echo "`date` [i] Already using gtk '${new_gtk_theme}' theme" >> ~/Scripts/switch-theme.log
    else
        echo "`date` [-] Setting gtk theme to ${new_gtk_theme}" >> ~/Scripts/switch-theme.log
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "${new_gtk_theme}"
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme "${new_color_scheme}"
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "${new_icon_theme}"
        echo "`date` [✓] gtk theme changed to ${new_gtk_theme}" >> ~/Scripts/switch-theme.log
    fi
}

# If script run without argument
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
    if [[ "$currenttime" > "19:00" || "$currenttime" < "10:00" ]]; then
        set_theme dark
    else
        set_theme light
    fi
else
    set_theme $1
fi
```

Finally, I [added this script at startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffroy.png) as well.