# Systemd Timer Not Running Automatically After a Reboot

Tags: systemd

Courtesy of @meuh, I managed to get Ubuntu to automatically switch between the "light" Window Theme and the "dark" Window Theme (see over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237805/help-with-creating-systemd-timers-to-automate-window-theme-changes))... But for some reason, systemd does not seem to be starting my timers after a reboot.

If I restart my system and run `systemctl --user list-timers`, it tells me that there are no timers... If follow this up with `systemctl --user restart dark.timer light.timer` and then run `systemctl --user list-timers` *again*, my timers show up correctly.

I have *repeatedly* run `systemctl --user enable dark.timer light.timer` before I restart my system, but as stated above, systemd seems to "forget" this and will *not* show these timers under *after* I have used the `systemctl --user restart dark.timer light.timer` command...

I feel confident that the solution is something trivial, but I have no idea what that solution might be, so any help the Community can provide would be appreciated.

--

Output of `ls ~/.config/systemd/user/*.target.wants`:

```
ls: cannot access '/home/gregory/.config/systemd/user/*.target.wants': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Add the output of `ls ~/.config/systemd/user/*.target.wants` to the question, please.

Comment: It seems there is a typo in my answer. Change `WantedBy=default.service` to `WantedBy=default.target` and do (as after any change) `systemctl --user daemon-reload`, then `systemctl --user reenable  dark.timer light.timer`.

Comment: Since this was a typo fixed in @meuh's answer, I'll vote to close as no-repro

Comment: All right. I made the changes and reloaded / re-enabled the timers... I'm gonna reboot and we'll see if it all worked this afternoon.

Comment: The timers are showing after a reboot, so it looks like it worked... Voting to "close" this question.  
  
Thanks, again @muru !