# Is there a way to shift the screen color hues with colors inverted?

Tags: color-management

I've managed to invert the screen with `xcalib -alter -invert`, but now blue is orange etc.

Isn't there a way to hue-shift the screen colors as well, so only the brightness is inverted and not the hue?

(side note: I figured out I can run OBS with a color correction filter to see my first monitor the way I want. It is a bit hacky though!)

Comment: Are you talking about a **text screen or graphical desktop environment** with application windows, for example `gnome-terminal` or `xterm`. Can you use ANSI sequences?

Comment: I'm talking about the full graphical desktop environment

Comment: Did you try with the same `xcalib` command and replace `-invert` with '-brightness` (short `-b`) according to 'man xcalib` at the internet (I have not installed this tool) or some other combination of options? An alternative might be to select another theme for the desktop (switch between a light and a dark theme). Maybe this link will help you: [Automatic Light / Dark Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234742/automatic-light-dark-mode)

Comment: Yeah normally I do `xcalib -alter -co 50` once or twice to dim the screen, but it would be even more convenient if I could replace white with black for text without turning people blue in images / videos

Comment: 'replace white with black for text': Do you mean subtitles or text in a terminal window?